# Context menu entry for .jpg files not showing anymore

Tags: context-menu, gimp, jpeg

My custom made context menu entry for .jpg files does not show up anymore in Windows 10.

I did the steps correctly by going into the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jpegfile\shell key, adding a new key there, give it a description in the standard-field, then add new sub-key "command" and define the command there. But it is still not showing. I suspect Windows somehow now handles image files differently, but am not sure.

I basically just want the option to open the image in GIMP directly there.

Comment: There is a maximum amount of context menu options.  How many do you currently have?

Comment: @Ramhound This is the only one I defined for jpegfiles. The other 3 are the standard ones "open", "edit" and "printto".
That beeing said, I recognized that the commands defined there don't work either, as I changed the "edit" command to open it with gimp, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the .jpg file extension (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jpg`) actually associated with the 'jpegfile' type?

Comment: Yes it is. The value 'jpegfile" is stored in the standard-value for .jpg. But it is also associated with another type called "image", that is stored in a REG_SZ called "PerceivedType", which now defines which entrys get shown. See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, for some reason, the actual context menu entrys for .jpgs, and probably a lot of other image files too, are now (Windows 10, 06.07.2021) handled in

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell
```

That is, because for the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jpg` key, a REG_SZ value called "PerceivedType" exists, which defines the behaviour for the context menu entrys when given, apparently.

Thanks for all the help, anyway.